# Strongest hydrogen bond between neutral molecules?

Tags: hydrogen-bond

It is known that very strong hydrogen bonds can occur in charged systems, such as $\ce{[F-}\ce{-H+-F-]}$, while hydrogen bonds in neutral systems are much weaker in comparison.

What is the strongest known hydrogen bond within the following specifications?

- both donor and acceptor monomers are neutral, and remain neutral upon association (no ionic bridges);
- heterodimers are allowed (e.g. hydrogen fluoride and ammonia);
- must be a single-site hydrogen bond - excluding dimers stabilized by multiple hydrogen bonds such as nucleobase pairs.

Comment: Well, you should change "possible" to known, otherwise it's speculation.

Comment: Also this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47346/do-symmetric-hydrogen-bonds-in-neutral-molecules-exist is highly relevant here.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a good target for [design golf](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4045/suggestions-for-molecular-design-golf-problems)...

Comment: It probably is $\ce{HF}$ and $\ce{NH3}$. It's hard to get a better donor and acceptor pair than that. It's always possible one could find some very obscure system where a hydrogen becomes quite positively charged, but for small molecules I'd be surprised if something beats $\ce{HF}$ and $\ce{NH3}$.