# Hydrogen + Fluorine Adiabatic Flame Temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

The theoretical adiabatic flame temperature of Hydrogen and Fluorine in their stoichiometric mixture is often quoted at around $\pu{4300K}$, such as in [this presentation](http://www.barc.gov.in/publications/nl/2011/pdf/DAE%20EA/Paper%2035.pdf) on page 2, or [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01155a579) which is shown entirely in the pubs preview. However, [this thermodynamics table](https://janaf.nist.gov/tables/F-005.html) from JANAF makes it seem as though the temperature should be much higher. I suspect I'm missing something, but after quite a lot of searching I can't find it! (So it's probably something very basic)

My work: The Gibb's energy for the reaction is quite negative even out to $\pu{6000K}$, so the combustion should happen effectively to completion regardless of temperature ($K = 307 = \exp\{--285.7\times1000/(8.314\times6000)\}$. The formation enthalpy is listed $\pu{-273kJ/mol}$, and we could either do the temperature integral of $C_p$, or scan down the H-H(Tr) column to find this puts us way beyond $\pu{6000K}$, let alone $\pu{4300K}$.

Anhydrous $\ce{HF}$ gas apparently does form [dimers](https://janaf.nist.gov/tables/F-006.html), [trimers](https://janaf.nist.gov/tables/F-007.html), etc. but these should only increase the adiabatic flame temp if present, and they (understandably) don't appear to be stable beyond a couple thousand K.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your assessment looks correct.

Comment: Glad it's not just me, thanks for giving it a look! There's a mystery afoot.